# Left/Right Audio Balance Locked Together on Bluetooth Headphones

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth, stereo

I'm using Windows 10. I'm a bit deaf on one side so I need to change volume balance of my bluetooth stereo headphones in Window's settings.

For some reasons, recently the L/R volume controls become locked together on these same headphones. It had been working fine in the past. I tried reinstalling the headphones from device manage but that didn't help.

The stereo is working when I press "test" under window's sound settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SetVol is a free command line program I wrote that may help you out.

It allows you to change the balance between the channels on an audio device.  The first channel is usually the left speaker, the second channel the right speaker.

[https://www.rlatour.com/setvol](https://www.rlatour.com/setvol/)

Hope it will be of help.

Comment: awesome! I'm now hoping there'll be a way to reliably lock the channel volume to a % of the master. I guess this can be done using a batch script with while loop that constantly gets the mastervolume using "setvol report" and then do "setvol %master% 100:30"

Answer (score 1):

To add to Rob's answer, I've written a batch script that can be run in the background to fix the L/R volume balance. By using this script the balance can be maintained at a constant ratio even if you set the master volume to 0 and then back up again.

```
@ECHO OFF
:loop
set i=0
for /f "delims== tokens=2" %%a in ('SetVol report') do (
    set /a mastervol=%%a
    goto :setbalance
)
:setbalance
SetVol.exe %mastervol% balance 100:40
TIMEOUT 2
goto loop
GOTO :EOF
```