# Unable to change audio balance on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, bluetooth

On my bluetooth headphones (JBL Tune 115bt), the left ear speaker is more quiet. To account for that, I tried to change the balance in the device properties. However, changing either the left or right channel also changes the other:

[image]

I am thus not able to change the balance. Is there any way to fix this (presumably) error or circumvent it?

In case they are needed, here are some system specifications: Windows 10 Home (20H2) 64bit. CPU: Intel Core i7-6500U. GPU: Nvidia GTX 950M.

The problem does not seem to be caused by the headphones since I can change the balance on my smartphone without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

In case someone else has the same problem, here is how I could resolve the problem (it actually wasn't too complicated):

One needs to turn off the absolute volume. This is described in this question: [Bluetooth wireless headphones will only change the volume from the headphones and not the computer](https://superuser.com/q/1612669/). Then one can change the balance using the normal Windows settings.

> 1. Open Windows Registry (regedit.exe).
> 2. Locate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT`
> 3. Create `REG_DWORD DisableAbsoluteVolume` and set it's value to **1**.
> 4. Restart your PC for changes to take affect.

The only possible downside is that changing the volume via the headset doesn't affect the volume display. However, it *is* possible to change the volume via the computer, too, which wasn't possible before.

Also, I found this question: [Left/Right Audio Balance Locked Together on Bluetooth Headphones](https://superuser.com/q/1348043/) which is essentially a duplicate of mine. Though the proposed solution there did not work for me which is why I will leave this question.

Comment: why not
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Bluetooth\Audio\AVRCP\CT
??
I would imagine its not necessarily the same...